# Почему position: sticky в некоторых случаях не работает?

Tags: css

Почему `position: sticky;` не срабатывает? Заметил, что в некоторых случаях работает, а в некоторых нет, но не могу понять почему.

```css
.parent {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
}

.left {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
}

.right {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 1000px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="sticky">sticky block</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    right block
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sticky двигается в пределах высоты родительского блока, но у него `height: auto` и высота в точности равна высоте sticky — двигаться банально негде. Уберите `<div class="left">`, и sticky начнёт успешно двигаться по высоте блока parent

Comment: Или просто растяните left на всю высоту любым доступным способом

Comment: @andreymal благодарю, проблема действительно в высоте блока `left`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Элемент позиционируется в соответствии с нормальным потоком документа, а затем смещается относительно его ближайшего *прокручивающего предка* и содержит [containing block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/All_About_The_Containing_Block) (ближайший предка уровня блока), включая элементы, связанные с таблицей, на основе значений `top`, `right`, `bottom`, и `left`. Смещение не влияет на положение любых других элементов.
>
> Это значение всегда создает новый stacking context. Обратите внимание, что липкий элемент «прилипает» к его ближайшему предшественнику, имеющему «механизм прокрутки» (созданный при  `overflow` от `hidden`, `scroll`, `auto`, или `overlay`), даже если тот не является ближайшим фактически прокручивающим предком. Это эффективно препятствует любому «липкому» поведению (см.  [Github issue on W3C CSSWG](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/865)).

Пример:

```css
#example-element-container {
  width: 350px;
}

.box {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, .2);
  border: 3px solid #00f;
  float: left;
  width: 65px;
  height: 65px;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
  padding-top: 1em;
}

.box+.box {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

#example-element {
  background-color: #ff0;
  border: 3px solid red;
  z-index: 1;
}

#example-element {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="example-element-container">
  <p>In this demo you can control the <code>position</code> property for the yellow box.</p>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box" id="example-element"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <p class="clear">To see the effect of <code>sticky</code> positioning, select the <code>position: sticky</code> option and scroll this container.</p>
  <p>The element will scroll along with its container, until it is at the top of the container (or reaches the offset specified in <code>top</code>), and will then stop scrolling, so it stays visible.</p>
  <p>The rest of this text is only supplied to make sure the container overflows, so as to enable you to scroll it and see the effect.</p>
  <hr>
  <p>Far out in the uncharted backwaters of the unfashionable end of the western spiral arm of the Galaxy lies a small unregarded yellow sun. Orbiting this at a distance of roughly ninety-two million miles is an utterly insignificant little blue green planet
    whose ape-descended life forms are so amazingly primitive that they still think digital watches are a pretty neat idea.</p>
</div>
```

Источник: [position - CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/position)